# What does a subscript + means?

Tags: notation, parameter-estimation

I am reading this paper about model selection that shows this expression for

$$\beta_j = (1 - \lambda\sqrt{pj}/||S_j||)_+ S_j$$

for the vectors $\beta_j$ of estimations.

From the text, the expression inside the parentheses is a number, but what does the + mean in this situation?

Comment: Without the context, we can only guess.

Comment: Depends on the context, but a common meaning, I believe, is$$(x)_+=\begin{cases}x&x>0\\0&x\leq0\end{cases}$$ This can be written as $(x)_+=(x+|x|)/2.$

Comment: But if you could tell us the topic of the text - the broad field of it - we are more likely to have a good guess.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I hough it was a common notation that only I didn't know. I will edit the question with some more details.

Comment: Can you share the source directly? It may be more obvious that way.

Comment: I think most likely @ThomasAndrews is correct: $x_+ = \max(x, 0)$. The paper should explain their notation somewhere.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I go it [here](https://www.columbia.edu/~my2550/papers/glasso.final.pdf)